# Is there an elegant way to convert vector<complex<float>> to vector<short>?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

My class is receiving a vector of complex floats, but the data stream packets must have the data as short. My solution is to first convert the data to short, then batch it into the packets, and send them. What would be the best method of converting this data?

The complex data should map to two separate variables: for example, `vcfSampleData[0].real()` -> `m_pData[0]`, and `vcfSampleData[0].imag()` -> `m_pData[1]` and so on.

```
void BufferSampleData(const std::vector<std::complex<float>>& vcfSampleData, const float& fTotalGain_dB, const Frequency& CentreFrequency, const Bandwidth& cBandwidth, const TimeStamp& tCaptureTime, const SampleRate& SampleRate)
{
    sBufferData* pWriteElement = m_SampleBuffer.GetWriteElement();
    if(pWriteElement != nullptr) {
        std::copy(vcfSampleData.begin(), vcfSampleData.end(), pWriteElement->m_pData); //vector<comlex<float>> must become vector<complex<short>> or vector<short>
        //other irrelevant stuff here
        m_SampleBuffer.CommitWriteElement();
    }
}
```

Comment: To help with the technical (syntax) part, we first need to know a `std::complex<float>` maps to one or more `short`s in your domain. How do you want to represent the information from two floating-point numbers using short integers?

Comment: use `std::transform`

Comment: Data streams just need to be streams of binary data. You can copy the memory to your stream as-is

Comment: @EyalK. It's a UDP stream, and has a specific packet type with a bunch of other metadata forming a standardised size, so the data needs to be in the correct format to be fetched correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a `std::` function that does what you are asking for, you'll just have to write a loop

```
pWriteElement->m_pData.reserve(vcfSampleData.size() * 2);
pWriteElement->m_pData.clear();
for (auto cmpl : vcfSampleData)
{
    pWriteElement->m_pData.push_back(cmpl.real());
    pWriteElement->m_pData.push_back(cmpl.imag());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

KISS.

```
void Transform (const std::vector<std::complex<float>>& vSrc, const std::vector<short>& vDst) {
    vDst.resize(2*vSrc.size());
    for (std::size_t i=0; i<vSrc.size(); i++) {
        vDst[2*i] = vSrc[i].real;
        vDst[2*i+1] = vSrc[i].imag;
    }
}
```